# Is .htaccess slowing down my dedicated server?

Tags: apache-2.2, hotlinking

First of all, I consider myself more a programmer than a servers guy. I have a website where I receive about 3,000 visits per day, which I think is a lot less than the max capacity for a dedicated server.

However, I've noticed that the connection to the website is pretty slow, e.g., to load images, to connect to it via SSH, etc.

I configured .httaccess recently to avoid hotlinking to images in my server (i.e. .jpg, .gif and .png), and I was wondering if that could be slowing down my website.

This is the configuration that I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|swf)$ http://www.google.com/ [R,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I found some code to do that in google, and I just copied to .htacces since I'm not an expert in apache. It works, but I don't know if that is the best way to do it.

How can I see if that is the reason why the server is slow? Are there any tools to monitor it? What would you do guys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

- *Is .htaccess slowing down my server?* Sure, probably, but maybe not enough that you care.  If you allow .htaccess files to override the server configuration, Apache needs to search all directories in a URL path for a .htaccess file (e.g., if you access /foo/bar/baz/index.html, then Apache needs to look for .../foo/bar/baz/.htaccess, .../foo/bar/.htaccess, .../foo/.htaccess, and .../.htaccess, where "..." is that path to your DocumentRoot).  This requires a finite amount of time which you can avoid if you put all your configuration in the server config files and set `AllowOverride None`.
- *Are there any tools to monitor server performance?*  There are a number of tools you can use to assess the performance of your server.  Apache ships with the `ab` tool ("Apache Bench"); see the man page for details.  Another popular solution is [Apache jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).  You would want to run tests with .htaccess files disabled and enabled and see if there's a noticeable difference.
- *What would you do guys?* If I had control over the server I would set `AllowOverride None` and put the configuration inside of an appropriate `<Directory>` or `<Location>` directive.

Comment: Since I have complete control of the server, I will probably put the configuration in the server config files. Thanks!